# Synonym for both addition and subtraction

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask, but will try anyway. Is there a term that can mean either subtraction or addition?

I'm working with a program that adds/subtracts up several numbers in the fibonacci sequence in one variable depending on whether the item is even or odd, and was wondering if there was a catch-all term that can mean both.

That way I can write something like: "The program *blanks* a sequence of fibonacci numbers, subtracting odd values and adding even ones."

Comment: Subtraction is just addition of a negative number, so the catch all term is just "addition". You could word your explanation as "The program sums a sequence of signed fibonacci numbers, treating odd values as negative and evens as positive."

Comment: [Linear combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) might be along the lines of what you’re looking for.

Comment: Accumulates ${}$

Answer (score 0):

The term “addition” *includes* “subtraction” (as addition of an additive inverse), too.

So your final sentence may be:

“The program **adds** a sequence of Fibonacci numbers, odd values with minus sign.”